# No real solution to logarithmic equation?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

$$e^x + 1 = 2e^{-x}$$

Wolfram Alpha claims no real solution and my text book claims the solution $x=0$.

Why can't I simply multiply each side by $e^x$:

$$e^{2x} + e^x = 2$$

$$\ln(e^{2x}) + \ln(e^x)=\ln(2)$$

$$3x = \ln(2)$$

$$x = \frac{\ln(2)}{3}$$

??

Comment: $0$ is indeed a solution since $e^0 = 1$ and $e^{-0} = \frac{1}{e^0} = 1/1 = 1$, and then you have $1+1 = 2(1) = 2$.

Comment: $\ln {(e^{2x}+ e^x) } \ne \ln {e^{2x}}+ \ln {e^x}$

Answer (score 3):

$\log(a+b) \neq \log(a)+ \log(b)$.

So, $\log(e^{2x}+e^x) \neq 3x$.

Comment: No, but $\log(e^{2x}) + \log( e^x) $ does equal $3x$?

Comment: Sure. but $\log(e^{2x} + e^x) \neq \log(e^{2x})+  \log(e^{x})$.

Comment: Right. Log is not associative like multiplication...THanks

Comment: Log isn't a binary operation so it can't be associative anyway. Log doesn't distribute over addition.

Comment: Log is a function, not a binary operation, right..

Answer (score 0):

As stated above you cannot do what you have done.

You must put $e^x=t$ and then form a quadratic in $t$. Then, you have to consider positive roots as $e^x>0$.

This will give you $t=-2,1 \implies t=1 \implies e^x=1 \implies x=0$.

[And never doubt wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=real%20solution%20%3a%20e%5Ex%2b1=2%2ae%5E%28-x%29)